# Javascript: hide/show content with css tabs

Tags: javascript, css, tabs, navigation

I've been trying to get this to work all day and I'm 95% there! Can someone please look at my code and help me with one (hopefully simple) thing? I've got 3 CSS tabs that change style when clicked (active vs. inactive) and shows the corresponding div content below. Everything is working (at least in Firefox) but what's got me annoyed is that the code I got (from http://www.digimantra.com/tutorials/simple-tabs-using-javascript-and-css/) uses “tabContent” and “tab1Content” with the same content in it. This essentially duplicates (in code) a large chunk of my site's content. (Users wouldn't see the difference, but I'm a stickler for clean code and can't bring myself to use this seemingly sloppy workaround!) Is there any way to get this to work without the duplicate content? (Please speak plainly to me; I'm a designer who codes xHTML and CSS by hand, and I know enough about js to be dangerous, but I can't code my own js from scratch. Forgive me!)

My working test with full code and css is here: http://www.happywivestravel.com/testTabToggle.html

The javascript in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tabs(x)
{
var lis=document.getElementById("sidebarTabs").childNodes; //gets all the LI from the UL

for(i=0;i<lis.length;i++)
{
  lis[i].className=""; //removes the classname from all the LI
}
x.className="selected"; //the clicked tab gets the classname selected
var res=document.getElementById("tabContent");  //the resource for the main tabContent
var tab=x.id;
switch(tab) //this switch case replaces the tabContent
{
  case "tab1":
    res.innerHTML=document.getElementById("tab1Content").innerHTML;
    break;

  case "tab2":
    res.innerHTML=document.getElementById("tab2Content").innerHTML;
    break;
  case "tab3":
    res.innerHTML=document.getElementById("tab3Content").innerHTML;
    break;
  default:
    res.innerHTML=document.getElementById("tab1Content").innerHTML;
    break;

}
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="tabContainer" >
<ul class="digiTabs" id="sidebarTabs">
<li id="tab1" class="selected" onclick="tabs(this);">Overview</li>
<li id="tab2" onclick="tabs(this);">Itinerary</li>
<li id="tab3" onclick="tabs(this);">Destination Info</li>
</ul>

<div id="tabContent"><p>Tab 1 content here...</p></div>
<div id="tab1Content" style="display:none;"><p>Tab 1 content repeated here...</p></div>
<div id="tab2Content" style="display:none;"><p>Tab 2 content here...</p></div>
<div id="tab3Content" style="display:none;"><p>Tab 3 content here...</p></div>
```

Thanks to anyone who has any ideas on this. I'm so close to getting what I want, it hurts! =)
(Just to be clear, my aim is to have a simple css-only (no images) tabbed navigation that changes appearance based on active/inactive tabs. I've looked into jQuery UI, but it seems a little massive for what I want, and I wanted easier/better control over the css.)

Comment: tabContent content keeps changing as you click on the tabs, eg. if u select tab3, its content will be copied in tabContent. i am sure u can find much better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the css is messed up, but i think it might help u.

**js**

```
$(function(){
    $(".t").bind("click",function(){
        $(".tabContent").each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        });
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#t"+id).show();
    });
});
```

**html**

```
    <div class="tabContainer" >
  <ul class="digiTabs" id="sidebarTabs">
    <li id="1" class="selected t" >
       Overview</li>

  <li id="2" class="t" >
     Itinerary </li>

   <li id="3" class="t">
      Destination Info</li>

  </ul>
   <div id="t1" style="display:none;" class="tabContent">
<h2>This sight will steal your  breath away!</h2>The Happy Wives are leaving their high heels home and donning a sensible  (albeit cute) pair of hiking boots for this adventure to Peru. Discover the ancient city of  Cusco, explore the ruins that lie along the Sacred Valley, and marvel at the lost Incan  city of Machu Picchu that's nestled atop the Andes Mountains. The Happy Wives turn this  traditional backpacker's adventure into a tour with class and style! (Backpack optional.)  [...]</div>    

<div id="t2"  class="tabContent" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida     Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px;display:none">
<p class="sale" style="border-bottom: 1px #666666;">YOUR TOUR INCLUDES:</p>
<ul class="tourIncludes">
<li>Roundtrip airfare from Minneapolis</li>
<li>9 nights in hand-picked hotels</li>
<li>Breakfast daily plus 1 dinner</li>
<li>Private driver to/from Sacred Valley</li>
<li>English-speaking guided tours in Lima, Cusco, and at Machu Picchu</li>
<li>2 days at Machu Picchu, including train/bus transportation</li>
<li>Your own personal travel assistant to guide you through Peru</li>
</ul>
 </div>  
 <div id="t3" class="tabContent" style="display:none;">The standard chunk of Lorem   Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.    </div>  

</div>
```

check this [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NIkhar/NRkL9/2/)

**updated js**

```
$(function(){

    $(".t").bind("click",function(){
        $(".t").each(function(){
         $(this).removeClass("selected");
        });
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(".tabContent").each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        });
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#t"+id).show();
    var res=document.getElementById("tabContent");
    });

});
```

Comment: I've been messing with this all morning/afternoon. I got the first tab's content to show on load (easy fix), but I still can't get the tabs to change appearance when they've been clicked. =/
http://jsfiddle.net/NRkL9/3/

Comment: !!! YAY !!! It's perfect! Thank you thank you thank you! I *knew* it could be done. You rock! =)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completion, if anyone else comes across this same issue, here's the working code in its entirety:

```
<!-- styles and scripts for sub nav tabs -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.tabContainer {
margin: 0;
}
.tabContainer .digiTabs {
list-style: none;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 1px;

}
.tabContainer .digiTabs li {
float: left;
background-color: #e7e5df;
padding: 5px 15px!important;
cursor: pointer;
border-bottom:none;
margin-right: 1px;
color: #801350;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}
.tabContainer .digiTabs .selected {
background-color: #fff;
color: #393939;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.tabContent {
padding: 20px;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$(".t").bind("click",function(){
    $(".t").each(function(){
     $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(".tabContent").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#t"+id).show();
var res=document.getElementById("tabContent");
});

});
</script>
<!-- end styles/scripts for subnav tabs -->

<!-- begin html container for tabs and content -->
<div class="tabContainer">
<ul class="digiTabs">
<li id="1" class="selected t">Overview</li>
<li id="2" class="t">Itinerary</li>
<li id="3" class="t">Destination Info</li>
</ul>

<!-- TAB 1 -->
<div id="t1" class="tabContent" style="display: block;">
<p>Content for tab 1.</p>
</div>
<!-- end tab 1 content -->

<!-- TAB 2 --> 
<div id="t2" class="tabContent" style="display: none;">
<p>Content for tab 2.</p>
</div>  
<!-- end tab 2 content -->

<!-- TAB 3 -->
<div id="t3" class="tabContent" style="display: none;">
<p>Content for tab 3.</p>
</div>  
<!-- end tab 3 content -->

</div>
<!-- end div class tabContainer -->
```

Thanks again, Nikhar for all your awesome help! =)